# Error: Too many arguments (need at most 2) when installing tmux plugins

Tags: linux, vim, tmux

I'm trying to install the `tmux-logging` plugin. So I:

1. Cloned `tmux-plugins/tmux-logging` from Github.
2. Created conf file `~/.tmux.conf`.
3. Added `run-shell ~/clone/path/logging.tmux` to bottom of the config file.

Next, I typed this in a terminal:

```
 $ tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

But I received an error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Do you have very strong reason to use Kali? This is not normal distribution, try with RHEL, Ubuntu, Debian,...

Comment: I was following this tutorial from the udemy. You can look it up here (go to configure kali linux TMUX), its a free preview so you watch it for free) https://www.udemy.com/course/cybersecurity-threat-hunting-for-soc-analysts/

Comment: So you do not have serious reason. As I said: switch to other distribution, Kali is not for you!

Comment: I do have a reason, I was trying to build a threat hunting home lab, so whats better than following a tutorial from there....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Not that this question would be any different on any other distribution, but I keep, *[If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/432493)* bookmarked for questions like this.

Comment: @islahdawson See [this great Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) on why you shouldn't post the error message as an image.  While I realize that you have *some* of the error message in your title, it's not complete, so it reduces searchability.

Answer (score 0):

This is the second question in 10 days here with what appears to be a significant misunderstanding in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging#manual-installation) for the `tmux-logging` plugin.  [Here's the other one](https://superuser.com/questions/1729743/logging-tmux-execution), although it will probably be [Roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) if it isn't reopened soon.

First, I'm surprised that both are attempting manual installation, when the instructions (immediately above the linked text) say:

> Installation with Tmux Plugin Manager (recommended)

But anyway, the manual installation shouldn't be too bad, but you (and the other poster) seem to be reading this wrong:

> Add this line to the bottom of `.tmux.conf`:
>
> `run-shell ~/clone/path/logging.tmux`

This is poorly worded, granted.  I think it would be more clear if it said something like:

```
run-shell <path_where_you_cloned_the_plugin>/logging.tmux
```

In other words, let's walk through a sample manual install up to that point:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/tmux/
cd ~/.local/share/tmux/
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging.git
```

Then you would add:

```
run-shell ~/.local/share/tmux/tmux-logging/logging.tmux
```

... to your `~/.tmux.conf`.

I'm still not sure that will take care of your particular error, though.  That points to some *other* problem in your config.  I would recommend starting with an *empty* config other than the line above.  Get the plugin working, then add back in any other configuration and determine which one (probably a `set-option` line) is causing that error.

I've tested the plugin on Kali myself with an empty (other than the `run-shell` line) and it works fine for me.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the great guidance! I have one more problem, currently i am unable to start logging. I use this command prefix (Ctrl B) + Shift P but nothing is showing that I am currently logging.